# Which class should i mock service class or third party api of service class?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, mocking

PostController's store method which calls the service class and service class calls the third party api i.e. line. while storing a post. i want to write testcase if the notify field is true then it sends notification to the user's through line if not then return with error message. i am not getting any idea how to perform this test. here is the code for PostController.php

```
private Post $post;
private PostService $service;

public function __construct(
    PostService $service,
    Post $post
) {
    $this->service = $service;
    $this->post = $post;
}

public function store(PostRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $post = $this->service->createPost($request->validated());
    if ($request->notify) {

        $message = 'lorem ipsum';
        $this->service->lineSendToGroup($request->category_big_id, $message);
    }

    return redirect()->to('/posts')->with('success_message', 'Post created successfully.');
}
```

PostService.php

```
use App\Library\Line;
use App\Models\CategoryBig;

class PostService
{
private CategoryBig $categoryBig;

public function __construct(
    CategoryBig $categoryBig,
) {
    $this->categoryBig = $categoryBig;
}

public function lineSendToGroup(int $categoryBigId, string $message): void
{
    $catB = $this->findOrFailCategoryBig($categoryBigId);
    Line::send(
        $catB->line_message_channel_secret,
        $catB->line_message_channel_access_token,
        $catB->line_group_id,
        $message
    );
}

public function findOrFailCategoryBig(int $categoryBigId): CategoryBig
{
    return $this->categoryBig->whereId($categoryBigId)->firstOrFail();
}

public function createPost(array $createData): Post
{
    $createData += [$data];
    return $this->greeting->create($createData);
}
```

Line.php

```
namespace App\Library;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use LINE\LINEBot;
use LINE\LINEBot\HTTPClient\CurlHTTPClient;
use LINE\LINEBot\Event\MessageEvent\TextMessage;
use LINE\LINEBot\MessageBuilder\TextMessageBuilder;
use Log;

class Line
{
    public static function send($channel_secret, $access_token, $line_user_id, $message)
    {
        $http_client = new CurlHTTPClient($access_token);
        $bot         = new LINEBot($http_client, ['channelSecret' => $channel_secret]);

        $textMessageBuilder = new TextMessageBuilder($message);
        $response    = $bot->pushMessage($line_user_id, $textMessageBuilder);

        if ($response->isSucceeded()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
    
public function test_notification_when_LINE_notification_is_specified()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1)**

You can write a unit test for `Line` class.

For ease of use, you can refactor this class and use Laravel [Http client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client) instead. Create different stubs for each line's response (e.g 200) then use Laravel [testing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#testing) helpers to mock resposne.

**Step 2)**

Write a feature test for your controller. In this test you don't care about internal functionality of Line class and just want to make sure method of this class is called with proper arguments.
You can use [mockery](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html) to achieve that.

> Migrate to non-static method on Line class. You can't mock static methods.

For happy path test:

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(\App\Library\Line::class);
    $mock->shouldReceive('send')
        ->once()
        ->with($secret, $token, $groupId, $message)
        ->andReturn(true);

// of course mocking object doesn't do much alone and you need to bind and resolve it.
$this->app->instance(\App\Library\Line::class, $mock);
```

Then [resolve](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#resolving) it inside your `PostService@lineSendToGroup`

```
resolve(Line::class, [
    'token' => $token,
    // ... other args

])
```

For opposite scenario use `shouldNotReceive('send')`  instead.

Comment: i got this mocking part but when notify is set to true it calls line api then returns to '/posts' url and when notify is set to false then it directly returns to '/posts' so i want to test if notify is true then line notification is sent? how to achieve this as return value is same weather notify is set to true or false???

Comment: ```$mock->once()->shouldReceive('send')``` Ensures that line message has been sent 
and for the opposite side you can use ``shouldNotReceive('send')`` instead. Also updated my answer to recap